# How to See Detailed 500 Errors?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, .net, 500-error

I have ii8 which I have tried to deploy my asp.net web api to. I guess I am doing something wrong as when I try to see if my api is working I am getting a 500 error.

However it does not tell me what the error is. How can I get more detailed information?

Answer (score 23):

In IIS Manager, select your site, double-click the `Error Pages` icon and click on `Edit Feature Settings` in the pane on the right. Choose `Detailed Errors`. If that is not enough, click on the `.NET Error Pages` in the `ASP.NET` section, again `Edit Feature Settings` in the pane on the right, choose `Off`.

If this is a production machine, change these settings back after you are done with debugging your code.

Comment: this literally changed nothing about the response for me so I tried an iis reset … still no luck :( using iis 10 though.

Comment: This answer helped me to find a way to see what was the issue in my webpage, it was really worth! Thank you!

Comment: I needed to do this for both the _site_ **and** the _server_ to get the detail to make it all the way to my browser (on another machine)

Answer (score 8):

IIS will, by default, show you detailed errors if you browse via localhost on the web server itself. That might help?

Comment: Simple, but easy to forget